# How to pass javascript variable in jstl fmt tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I want to pass one textfield value in jstl fmt tag at onblur event.
I am using below code but does not working.

js code:

```
function setPercentage(id){
   var idVal = $('#'+id).val();
   alert('<fmt:formatNumber type="percent" maxIntegerDigits="3" value="${idVal}"/>');   
}
```

html code:

```
<input type="text" id="myValue" onblur="setPercentage('myValue')"/>
```

onBlur I am getting nothing..
please help me..

Comment: sorry... the HTML code?

Comment: _onBlur I am getting nothing..._ if you could explain it.

Comment: It doesn't work like this. You'll need to format the number in JavaScript. JSTL runs on the server; JS on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got one answer from chat.stackoverflow i.e.
javascript is executed on the client side while jstl is server side.
So it is not possible to passjavascript varaible in jstl fmt tag.

we can use any request or session value in jstl fmt tag within  using EL.

js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function setPercentage(){
   alert('<fmt:formatNumber type="percent" maxIntegerDigits="3" value="${idVal}"/>');   
 }
</script>
```

here idVal is request or session scoped value.